# How to pick a random number from a list, only once, using C

Tags: c, arrays, random, srand

So i have an array of integers that go from 0 to 27.

```
for(i<0; i<28; i++)
{
    ListId[i] = i;
}
```

What I want to do is to pick a number from that array and re-order it in another array, randomly.

I've tried to replaced the number already picked, by a flag, the number -1:

```
for(i<0; i<28; i++)
{
    RandomId[i] = i;
    ListId[i] = i;
}

srand(time(NULL));

for(i=0; i<28; i++)
{
    res = rand() % 27;
    aux = ListId[res];

    if (ListId[res] != -1)
    {
        RandomId[i] = aux;
        ListId[res] = -1;
    }
    else
        i--;
}

printf("New list of integers: ");

for(i=0; i<28; i++)
{
    printf("%d | ", RandomId[i]);
}
```

But in ends into an infinite loop.

Hope someone can help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Notice your first for loop: for(i<0;i<28;i++)

Comment: I was going to propose decrementing your `ListId` length by 1 -- a common trick -- but since your output list has the same length, why not use a random shuffle instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice your first for loop: `for(i<0;i<28;i++)`

And notice your: `res = rand() % 27;` ... should be `28`.

The range of `% N` is 0 to (N-1), hence your 27 results with the range 0-26.